# how to unzip / extract tgz.part-af file with python?

Tags: python, linux-kernel, extract, unzip, 7zip

I want to unzip it. The file size is almost 5GB

```
import tarfile
fname = x_geotiff.tgz.part-af
opener, mode = tarfile.open, 'r:gz2'
tar = tarfile.open(fname, "r:gz") # gz,gz2,bz,bz2,* do not work as it is part-af file
tar.extractall()
tar.close()
```

**Windows user**

Comment: What do you mean by "do not work"? It throws an exception? Or what? And have you tried to use just `"r"` as a mode, when `tarfile.open` tries to autodetect a format of the file?

Comment: @Tsyvarev https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html